# Google Chart Dashboards in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find the best way to convert the following Google charts javascript sample to ReactJS.

My challenge is how can I get the change in the proxyTable chart to trigger a change in the other charts (columnChart & areaChart) by following the general Google charts convention by using the event triggers?

Snippet of of code that is working in pure javascript:

```
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'slider_div',
    ...
});


var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    ...
});

var areaChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'AreaChart',
    ...
});

var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    ...
});


// create a "ready" event handler for proxyTable the handles data aggregation and drawing chart
google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {

    var dt = proxyTable.getDataTable();

    var groupedData=google.visualization.data.group(dt, 
                                                    [0], 
                                                    [{'column': 9, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
                                                        {'column': 10, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}
                                                    ]
                                                    );   

    columnChart.setDataTable(groupedData);
    columnChartBinUtilization.draw();

});



// create a "ready" event handler for proxyTable the handles data aggregation and drawing chart
google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {

    var dt = proxyTable.getDataTable();

    var groupedData=google.visualization.data.group(dt, 
                                                    [0], 
                                                    [{'column': 9, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
                                                        {'column': 10, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}
                                                    ]
                                                    );   

    areaChart.setDataTable(groupedData);
    areaChart.draw();

});

// draw dashboard
dashboard.bind(slider,proxyTable)
dashboard.draw(data);
```

Initially, I tried to create a Chart component, but I can't wrap my head around how to get the other Chart components (areaChart & columnChart) hooked up to update when the filter is applied on the proxyTable chart. (The above javascript sample above works fine)

Answer (score 0):

it's my opinion:

- you just create and a new element `script` and then put the script in the main thread of your browser you can use `document.body` or `document.head` to push your new script, and you change the `new google.otherFunc` with `window.google.otherFun`
- to listen a change in your `proxyTable` variable you can use `componentDidUpdate` in class component or using `useEffect` if you using functional component